# include not parsing template file

Tags: java, freemarker, ofbiz

I have three very simple files:

**main.ftl**

```
<#include "header.ftl">

<h1>Test</h1>

<#include "footer.ftl">
```

**header.ftl**

```
<h1>Header</h1>
```

**footer.ftl**

```
<h1>Footer</h1>
```

Technically it should output three `h1`'s however my actual output is:

[image]

1. I read that depending on the configuration the brackets for ftl might change from `<` and `>` to `[` and `]`, I've tried changing but still nothing.
2. I've used the `*` wildcard which checks parent directories and the current directory and still no luck.
3. Freemarker documentation states that by default the `include`
   directive parses the content as a `.ftl` file so I should have no
   issues:

> parse: If it is true, then the included file will be parsed as FTL, otherwise the whole file will be considered as simple text (i.e, no FreeMarker constructs will be searched in it). If you omit this option, then it defaults to true.

So why isn't my template being parsed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Freemarker wasn't processing the `.ftl` file as an actual `.ftl` file as the server was rendering the content as a `.jsp` file, to fix I changed:

```
<view-map name="frs" page="">
```

to,

```
<view-map name="frs" type="screen" page="component://ecommerce/widget/CommonScreens.xml#your-identifier"/>
```

which fixed the rendering. By default if the `type` property is not defined then it is automatically rendered a JSP file.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of future readers... The `#include` directive never outputs itself like `<#include ...>` (so as you now know, it's `main.ftl` that's not passed to FreeMarker). Its `parse` parameter applies to the includ**ed** file. Also if a template is not found, it will throw an exception, not doing something arbitrary like printing `<#include ...>`.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_include.html).

```
<#include "/common/copyright.ftl">
```

So I presume the footer and header are in the same folder as your main file. So you will have to do something like:

```
<#include "*/header.ftl">
<#include "*/footer.ftl">
```

Comment: Yep, it isn't parsing.

Comment: Oh I just checked again, you are supposed to use * instead of . I will edit my answer please try again.

Comment: Have you tried adding parse=true. Like so <#include "*/footer.ftl" parse=true>

Comment: Note that if a template is not found, then the template processing throws an exception. So the problem can't be related to not finding the included template.